# Receiving two HTML input fields using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, double

I've been trying to create a `combobox`, essentially a form, with two input fields.

This is my combobox:

```
<select name="answers[]" id="answers">
<option value="<?PHP echo $cevap_list['CRM7101']; ?>,<?PHP echo $cevap_list['CRM7105']; ?>"><?PHP echo $cevap_list['CRM7103']; ?></option>
```

I tried to receive this values in a PHP script the form POSTs to:

```
$answers= $_POST['answers']; 

for($p=0;$p<=count($answers);$p++){ 
    $answer_explode = explode(",",$answers[$p]);  
    $answer_id = $answer_explode[0];  
    $answer_value = $answer_explode[1]; 
} 

for($i=0;$i<count($answer_id);$i++){ 
$cevapkontrol = trim($answer_id[$i]); 

 $sorgu = mysql_query("insert into CRM9001(CRM9107,CRM9106) values ('".$answer_value[$i]."','".$answer_id[$i]."') "); 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the value exactly? What does the SQL query look like you're executing?

Comment: the value is <?php
$CRM6101 = $soru_list['CRM6101'];
$answer_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CRM7001 where CRM7104 = $CRM6101 ORDER BY CRM7101 ASC");

Comment: No, the ***value***. What is the value of `$answer_value[$i]` and/or `$CRM6101` or whatever. Not the variable name, we can see that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construction
2. You are overriding previous id and value on each iteration

> ```
> <?php
>
> if ($_POST)
> {
>     $results = array();
>     foreach ($_POST['answers'] as $answer)
>     {
>         $answer_explode = explode(",", $answer);
>         $results[] = array(
>             'value' => trim($answer_explode[1]),
>             'id' => trim($answer_explode[0])
>         );
>     }
>
>     foreach($results as $result)
>     {
>         mysql_query("insert into CRM9001(CRM9107,CRM9106) values ('".$result['value']."','".$result['id']."') ");
>     }
> }
> ```

```
<select name="answers[]">
    <option value="some_id,some_value">some_name</option>
</select>
<select name="answers[]">
    <option value="some_id2,some_value2">some_name2</option>
</select> <input type="submit">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have a problem. I have so many values from the form. for example textboxes and more. how can i add these values to the foreach ?

Comment: In the same way. `foreach($_POST['form_element_name'] as $value)`

Comment: can you write some example about this. for example this combobox and 3 textbox in the form. but the textboxes have question_id and exam_id values.

Comment: Dude, read some manuals first... Try to google at least something. I can do it later tonight, but first of all tell me please what exactly you want to do.

Comment: i have exam form. This form includes comboboxes and textareas. All comboboxes values comming from mysql db. i put the values which are needed in combobox value area (exam_id, question_id, answer_id, answer_value). I used your codes and it's worked. But i don't know how can i save textareas into database. Because i explode the values from combobox, but textarea doesn't have value from database. Users will fill textareas. So i have anything for explode when i get the textares. so how can i save all values from form to the database? i really wanna learn this question of answer.